# How to check all types of error in a new created python file/module?

Tags: python

As asked in the title.. I am creating a new '.py' file using python. It contains certain code which I write into the '.py' file. Now, I want to check if there are any syntax errors, indentation errors etc. (in short all kinds of error) in that file. How to proceed?

P.s - I want to do it using python only and not any IDE and extensions.
P.s- Thanks in advance.

I tried using python's os module, in that exists() function. It returns True.
Tried with python's 'identify' library.

Comment: Use an IDE (Integrated development environment Software), like VS Code and install the Python extension, which will use Pylance to check for syntax errors and more.

Comment: @user56700 i want to do it using python and not any IDE and extensions.

Comment: Maybe you should add that to the question then?

Comment: Have you tried _running_ your program? The interpreter will tell you what the errors are.

Comment: @user56700 Noted. Updated the question.

Comment: @ndc85430 Yes..it prompts error correctly. But according to my use case i want to check for any issues before hand, using python.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do such check.

all [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org) links are given for `python3.8`

### using the [compile](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#compile) function

Thi is is the shortest way to do such check.

function `compile(source, filename, mode)` does compile source code (as present in your *.py files) into a code object (as *.pyc files, `function.__code__` etc.).

When compiling, none of the commands from `source` will be executed – compiling is pre-runtime phase. But if syntax is wrong, corresponding error raise.

Example:

```py
with open('code.py') as file:
    s = file.read()

try:
    compiled = compile(s, 'code.py', 'exec')
    print('no errors found')
except BaseException as msg:
    print(type(msg).__name__, msg)
```

**code**, which **compile()** returns, can be passed into **exec()** to execute

### using [parser.suite](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/parser.html#parser.suite)

This is in case you are going to analyze your source deeper.

function `parser.suite(source)` parses source to prepare it for analyze.

This parsed source
These are equivalents:

```py
code_a = compile(s, 'file.py', 'exec')
code_b = parser.compilest(parser.suite(s))
print(code_a == code_b) # => True
```

Modified check example:

```py
import parser

with open('code.py') as file:
    s = file.read()

try:
    code = parser.suite(s)
    print('no errors found')
except BaseException as msg:
    print(type(msg).__name__, msg)
```

### using the [ast.parse](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.parse) function

AbstractSyntaxTree (ast) is another python built-in module for source code parsing, and it can be useful for further code analyzing.

**parser** and **ast** are using a different parsing approach. One (maybe not the key) of the differences is that **parser** is more like python interpreter which sees python code, and **ast** is more human-readable.

These are equivalents:

```py
code_a = compile(s, 'file.py', 'exec')
code_b = compile(ast.parse(s, filename='file.py'), 'file.py', 'exec')
print(code_a == code_b) # => True
```

Modified check example:

```py
import ast
with open('code.py') as file:
    s = file.read()

try:
    ast.parse(s, filename='file.py')
    print('no errors found')
except BaseException as msg:
    print(type(msg).__name__, msg)
```

### additional links

[full grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/grammar.html?highlight=grammar%20specification)